# Creation/annihilation operators relation in equation 2.46 of Peskin and Schoroeder

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hamiltonian, commutator

We can get the following relations from the creation/annihilation operators:

$$
H^n a_p = a_p (H - E_p)^n,
$$
and

$$
H^n a_p^{\dagger} = a_p^{\dagger} (H + E_p)^n.
$$

How do we get that

$$
e^{iHt} a_p e^{-iHt} = a_p e^{-iE_p t}
$$

and

$$
e^{iHt} a_p^{\dagger} e^{-iHt} = a_p^{\dagger} e^{iE_p t}?
$$

Actually, why we can say that

$$
\phi(x) = \phi(\vec{x},t) = e^{iHt}\phi(\vec{x})e^{-iHt}
$$

Comment: Hint: try expanding the exponentials in Taylor series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just expand the exponential $e^{iHt}$.

$$\begin{aligned}e^{iHt} a_p e^{-iHt}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(iHt)^n}{n!}a_p\ e^{-iHt},\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_p\frac{(iHt-itE_p)^n}{n!}e^{-iHt},\\
&=a_p e^{it(H-E_p)}e^{-iHt},\\
&=a_p e^{-itE_p}.\end{aligned}$$

Similarly you can compute the same thing for the creation operator.

Answer (score 2):

**Mathematician's answer**

To prove $e^{iHt}a_p=a_pe^{i(H-E_p)t}$, add the first equation times $(it)^n/n!$ for $n\ge0$. Prove $e^{iHt}a_p^\dagger=a_p^\dagger e^{i(H+E_p)t}$ by using the second equation the same way. To get the last part from these results, write $\phi(\vec{x}),\,\phi(x)$ as $\vec{p}$-space integrals.

**Physicist's answer**

To prove $a_pe^{-iHt}=e^{-i(H+E_p)t}a_p$, note both operators let a time $t$ pass and delete an energy-$E_p$ particle. Prove $a_p^\dagger e^{-iHt}=e^{-i(H-E_p)t}a_p^\dagger$ the same way. To prove $e^{-iHt}\phi(\vec{x},\,t)=\phi(\vec{x},\,0)e^{-iHt}$, note [both operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Pictures_in_quantum_mechanics) let a time $t$ pass and introduce a $\phi$-at-$t=0$ factor.